# Tangent and implicit differentation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, implicit-differentiation

So I'm studying implicit differentiation and running into a bit of a dilemma.

On the unit circle, the slope of a tangent line at a point is just the tangent of the angle to that point. So the way I'm interpreting this is that the rate of change between points on the unit circle is related to the tangent of those angles, or sin/cos.

But through implicit differentiation, you get a rate of change of -x/y on the unit circle, which is -cos/sin.

I have to be misunderstanding something because these are obviously two very different values.

Comment: Are you sure about that first assertion? The angle to $(1,0)$ is $0$, but $\tan0=0$, which is certainly not the slope of a vertical line. Maybe you’re thinking of the _normal_ to the circle instead.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265706/is-the-tangent-function-like-in-trig-and-tangent-lines-the-same?rq=1 for clarification

Comment: @amd Yep, that's where I was going wrong I think. The tangent of an angle is the slope of the line perpendicular to the tangent line and not the slope of the tangent line itself.